# How To Repeat Cell Value X Times In Excel One Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet like this

[image]

Can you please let me know how I can loop on column `A` based on column `B` and create comma separated with `-0` , -01` .... to column C

Comment: should it look like the two examples (C2 and C3)? How many loops? Through the whole column? That might not be possible depending on how many rows you are using.

Comment: loops are based on column `B` but I need to apply to all rows ofcourse

Comment: do you want to loop "automatically" (with VBA or Matrix formula) or "manually" (with a regular formula)?

Comment: well I prefer not VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CONCATENATE in combination with an IF formula. This would be an example of what to put in C2:

```
=IF(B2=1,CONCATENATE(A2,", ","-0"),IF(B2=2,CONCATENATE(A2,", ","-0",", ",A2,", ","-1"),IF(B2=3,CONCATENATE(A2,", ","-0",", ",A2,", ","-1",", ",A2,", ","-2")))
```

It's just an example, because you did not specify you're requirements completely in might very in your case.

I had to "translate" the formula from German notation and I could't test it, there might be an error you have to correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 Excel we can make it a bit more dynamic.  this will do as many as wanted without the need to increase the formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,INDEX(A2,N(IF({1},ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,B2))-ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,B2))+1))))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode

It creates an array of the value the number of times desired and passes that array to the TEXTJOIN that puts the comma in place.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came across this topic looking for an answer. I like it very much @Scott Craner solution, you can also use this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX(A2,N(IF(1,1^ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B2))))))
```

Confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>